# Minimise the sum of ratios

Tags: combinatorics, matching-theory

I have a list $a$ whose elements are positive real values. Assume $a_i > a_2 > ... a_{n-1} > a_n$, and assume $n$ is even. You must form unique pairs from $a$ and for each pair's value is given by $\frac{a_i}{a_j}$, and $a_i < a_j$. The goal is to minimise the sum of these ratios, and for each solution the pairs must be unique and each element can be chosen only once. Example, $a = \{4,3,2,1\}$. There are three possible solutions, and one of them is $S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}$.

If this is a well known problem, I apologise, and if so I would like to be directed to material or other similar questions that would help.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you notice a pattern in the minimum for $n = 4$? What about $n = 6$?

Answer (score 2):

Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

Prove the following "obvious" statements:

- We want to minimize the numerators and maximize the denominators, so the numerators should be $ \{ a_n, a_{n-1} \ldots a_{n/2 + 1 } \}$ and the denominators should be $ \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$.
- The minimum occurs at

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{ a_{n/2 + i} } { a_{0+i} } $$

EG For the $a = \{4, 3, 2, 1 \}$ case, the minimum is $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{4}$.

One approach is to:

> Apply the rearrangement inequality

Comment: Based on what I have simulated in code so far, this does hold. 

I do not know if for the globally optimal solution, the maximum sum is relevant: but I do know that the maximum does not always occur while choosing pairs $(a_i, a_{i+1})$, which is the intuitive thing, to make them as close as possible in value. Although it is usually the case. 

it should be noted that I am using np.random.uniform() to generate the elements of the list.

Comment: I want the minimum sum. I was just stating that the maximum sum is not consistently the same pairing for sure.

Comment: I put on the constraint that the numerator must be smaller than the denominator.

Comment: Ah ic. Let me rethink that.

Comment: @Adenine Can you provide a counter example when $\sum a_{2n} / a_{2n-1} $ isn't the maximum? I think that it is, so I'd like to see the counter example and I can check it against my quick crude reasoning.

Comment: Sure, consider the sorted list [0.96, 0.82, 0.77, 0.24]

Here the maximum is 0.24/0.96 + 0.77/0.82 = 1.189..
where as $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ 0.24/0.77 + 0.82/0.96 = 1.166..

Comment: @Adenine Ah thanks. That was the case that I thought would obviously work out, but in fact doesn't when "0.77" is large enough (larger than $0.756$ in this case). You might want to pose the maximum variant of this question, and share what you've done so far.